# Entity Framework - map nullable column to not null in entity

Tags: entity-framework

In a large legacy application a nullable database `bit`  which shall be mapped in Entity Framework to a `bool` property.

Is such a mapping possible that Entity Framework treats `null` and `0` automatically as `false`?

Comment: maybe try adding some default value for the column (null will be treated as 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EF model should match the database, so if the DB column is nullable your property should be nullable.

So you could either:

1) have in your partial definition of your entity some non-nullable property in addition to the nullable one:

```
public bool MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.MyNullableProperty ?? false;
    }

    set
    {
        this.MyNullableProperty = value;
    }
}
```

2) map your entities to a view that exposes non-nullable values.